# Isometry and its inverse

Tags: linear-algebra

I got this affine map:

$$
f: R^3  \rightarrow R^3: \begin{pmatrix}x\\
y\\
z\\\end{pmatrix} \rightarrow A \cdot \begin{pmatrix}x\\
y\\
z\\\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}0\\
-1\\
1\\\end{pmatrix}
$$

with $$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & a_{12} & a_{22}\\
0 & 1 & a_{21}\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Also given was this information about the inverse (which should also be an affine map?):
$$
g=f^{-1}: R^3  \rightarrow R^3: \begin{pmatrix}x\\
y\\
z\\\end{pmatrix} \rightarrow B \cdot \begin{pmatrix}x\\
y\\
z\\\end{pmatrix} + \bar b
$$

I have to find $\bar b$. Does anyone have an idea how to find it? I tried inputting some values but I can't seem to get there.

Comment: A linear function maps $0$ to $0$, so $f$ is not linear...

Comment: Ignoring the very obvious abuse of notation and language, think about what the inverse function (say $g$) maps $0$ to?

Comment: I edited the notation, but realised I could edit the grammar too - woe is me

Answer (score 1):

So $f$ is an isometry (that is, it's bijective and can be seen as a translation (the $ + \bar a$) and rotation ($A \cdot \bar x$).
As you can see geometrically, they must have inverses, because I can translate back and rotate again.

HINT: Let $g$ be the inverse. Then $g(\bar 0) = \bar b$. So $f(\bar b) = 0$ as they are inverses. Now that looks like an equation we can solve.

I'll answer completely in a while, but I'd rather you do the next step first.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this but I'm not really able to figure it out yet? I don't think that's an equation I can quite solve but I might just be wrong?

Comment: call $\bar b = [b_1, b_2, b_3]^T$. Then evaluate $f(\bar b)$. You should get three linear equations. I think that's pretty soluble.

Answer (score 0):

$\overline{b} = g(0) = f^{-1}(0)$, so solve $f(x) = 0$ so $Ax = (0,1,-1)$. The answer (which depends on the 3 constants in $A$) is the required $\overline{b}$.